# is there any netbeans pluggin that can work as subtitute of jindent?

Tags: netbeans

Maybe it's the wrong place to ask this kind of question, but I am giving it a shot cause stack's probably the best place to have an answer for other programmers. So, it there any third party or netbeans plugin that can be substitute of jindent, a tool to structure our code?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what needs do you have, where even the format option isn't enough, in Netbeans?

Comment: @james black : thank you, i use it for months but never use it even once by one. thanks. now i have to set up it. where is the option i wonder..hmm maybe in options.

Comment: @jame black : it's great but not enoght. how do we use it to inspect a projects with tons of files and code lines  ?

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking to batch process a bunch of files without having to load each one into the IDE and format it?

Comment: @arnold spence : yes, that's what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do "batch" processing of a lot of files, you may not need a solution that is specific to Netbeans. There are alot of options linked in this SO question: [Stand-alone Java code formatter/beautifier/pretty printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/manual/plugin-netbeans.html

Jalopy does the job very well and is even able to format files with guarded sections