# Programmatically format and indent automatically generated source from Java

Tags: java, netbeans, code-generation, code-formatting

I wrote code generator that creates Java and C++ source code from custom IDL using Antlr. It works perfectly except for the Java code formatting. Currently I use Gnu Indent, but the format that it spits out is hardly readable and makes debugging a pain. I would love to use the same code formatter as NetBeans does (like when you press Alt+Shift+F) to format the generated files. What I do not want is to go through each of these files and manually pressing Alt+Shift+F. I tried using the NetBeans API, but either I am not looking in the right places or Google is being an idiot, I cannot find a proper working example to do this on files not loaded in the editor...

Can someone at least guide me towards the right direction for this?

Comment: In Eclipse you can execute the "format code" shortcut while the project (or a folder/package) is select and every Java source inside of it will be formatted. Maybe this works in Netbeans as well.

Comment: I want to do this from my code generator, it can be run from the command line as well, which should spit out nicely formatted Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: Not interested in a stand alone application to invoke after my source has been generated. I am already using GNU Indent to do this, and it feels slow! It takes about 5 minutes on a fast machine to go through all the generated source!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/18365/format-files

Comment: Or use NB 7.2, when it is out. 
"The Source/Format action should work on packages, folders, source groups and projects"

Details https://www.netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67397#c3

Answer (score 1):

[Jalopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jalopy/)

Comment: Have you ever tried using Jalopy in your code? The open source version hasn't been active for the past 6 years... I am not willing to pay for commercial version, the NetBeans API can do it already and its free.