# Pretty HTML snippet output

Tags: java, html, jsoup, transform, pretty-print

I've a snippet of HTML `<div><p>text1</p></div><div><p>text1</p></div>`

I want to make it pretty like this

```
<div>
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
```

What would be most simple way to do it? (I've looked on transform and jsoup) but not sure what would be really smart to use. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, somehow I missed this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jTidy could fit for this task - http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html

```
public String prettyPrintHTML(String rawHTML)
{    
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    tidy.setIndentContent(true);
    tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
    tidy.setTidyMark(false);

    // HTML to DOM
    Document htmlDOM = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawHTML.getBytes()), null);

    // Pretty Print
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.pprint(htmlDOM, out);

    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid auto-adding head and body to my result? I have to parse only snippet.

Comment: I have set `tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);` - that should do it. If it's still wrapped, simply fetch the content of the node body from htmlDOM. `Node body =  htmlDom.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);`

Comment: what if I need to pretty have [header part] only but not a body?

Comment: Remove `tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);`. You get the full doc. Then again work with the htmlDom and extract the header node. `Node head = htmlDom.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);`

Comment: It also replace some new html5 tags to div :( can't really use it then

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) like

```
String html = "<div><p>text1</p></div><div><p>text1</p></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
```

But this will wrap your text into

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    ..
  </body>
</html>
```

To get rid of this part you can get part from `<body>` like

```
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

which prints

```
<div>
 <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p>text1</p>
</div>
```

If you want to increase indentation you can set it earlier with

```
doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(4);
```

now result will look like

```
<div>
    <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>text1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) here is an [online version](http://infohound.net/tidy/).

Many of the text editors have plugins or built in functionality for this.

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

[BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)

[Coda](https://panic.com/coda/)

Comment: How can I avoid adding body and html? I want to have pretty only my snippet.

Comment: It depends when you are trying to do this. Do you want to do this on the fly so your code is sent to a page formatted or are you trying to do this while you are editing it?

Comment: I need to display snippets of html our page is combined from.
Some customer want to see snippets separately instead of viewing HTML on page.