# How can I easily fix Checkstyle errors?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is there a way to have an IDE fix Checkstyle errors automatically without having to fix each manually?

Comment: Related question: [coding style - Stand-alone Java code formatter/beautifier/pretty printer? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, yes. You can't correct all problems though. There are two ways:

1. Right click on the java file in Package Explorer or whatever, and select 'Apply Checkstyle Corrections'.
2. Click on the error in the problems view, and select 'Quick fix'. This corrects the problem.

Comment: If I am using Netbeans then how can I do that. Can you please help? Thanks. :)

Comment: Is there something in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using IntelliJ, you can install the [CheckStyle IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea).

Then [import the CheckStyle settings into the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273850/2062384), and Reformat like normal (Ctrl+Alt+L is default shortcut key).

Comment: Docs on shortcut keys: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#reformat_rearrange_code

Comment: Additionally, make sure that if you have a .editorconfig file that you delete it or comment out any conflicting styles. The .editorconfig will take precedence and prevent the reformat command from using the checkstyle settings.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather vague, but I think what you're asking is if CheckStyle can automatically reformat code that it's checking to fix code layout problems that it finds.

The direct answer here is "no."

However, there are a number of "Java source code formatters" (google that, choose one) that will do what I believe you're asking for.

Comment: I figured that my question is rather stupid, I should have checked for the tons of plugins at the Checkstyle site. You're right, my question doesn't make sense. I edited it. Thanks a lot for your input though!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this every time you save your file but not all warnings in Checkstyle can be fixed automatically.

You can have Checkstyle generate a formatter for you by right clicking on your package in the Package/Project explorer and selecting *Checkstyle->Create Formatter-Profile*. This will create a new formatter called *eclipse-cs [your-package-name]* based off of your Checkstyle configuration. You'll find it in the "Active profile" drop-down in the formatter preferences of Eclipse.

You can then set the formatter to run each save by going to *Preferences->[Language of Choice]->Editor->Save Actions*. Check the "Perform the selected actions on save" and "Format source code" boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I created a feature request for the Eclipse checkstyle plugin to also support quick fixes from within the code editor:
https://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-cs/feature-requests/150/

Answer (score 0):

I used jalopy. Create Tool to fix the Check style issues.

Comment: For anyone wondering, here is the link: https://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/
(It's unfortunately not free though)