# Maven checkstyle error during mvn eclipse:eclipse

Tags: java, maven, netty

Currently I just tried to download and build to make the Netty source code work. But when I tried to run the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the source folder. I got an error said

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:check (check-style) on project netty-common: Failed during checkstyle execu
tion: There are 304 checkstyle errors. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:check (check-style) on proj
ect netty-common: Failed during checkstyle execution
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:352)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed during checkstyle execution
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:374)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleExecutorException: There are 304 checkstyle errors.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:218)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:365)
```

It is error of the checkstyle plugin when validating the code `netty-common` project.

I am not familiar with this plugin . I want to know if I can just ignore it by removing the configuration from the pom.xml(in the ). like below.

```
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>check-style</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                  <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                  <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                  <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                  <configLocation>io/netty/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                  <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-build</artifactId>
                <version>21</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore use import into Eclipse as Maven project.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CheckStyle is a module of maven that check the style of the code for things like tabs instead of spaces. Netty is using this to prevent basic formatting mistakes.

If you are planning to contribute to Netty, you should NOT remove the plugin as it probably means your patch will never applied.

If you are just using to play with, you are free to remove that plugin as its only purpose is to verify the installation, and not to change things from the installation.

If you choose to keep it, you should look in the output log to see what the mistakes are it detected, to quickly fix the mistakes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417213/1542723) answer by [Matthew Farwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836/matthew-farwell).

> 1. Right click on the java file in Package Explorer or whatever, and select 'Apply Checkstyle Corrections'.
> 2. Click on the error in the problems view, and select 'Quick fix'. This corrects the problem.

Comment: After I faced the error I searched my project folder for the string "checkstyle", but didn't find anything. grep -i "checkstyle" -r . So it's interesting what triggers this check...

Answer (score 61):

Skip the check style execution using

```
-Dcheckstyle.skip
```

Ex

```
mvn [YOUR_COMMAND] -Dcheckstyle.skip
```

Comment: This works on your local machine, but not if you want to commit a patch to the Netty project.

Comment: This works. My case is different. I wanted to "mvn clean install" a spark project.  I did not have maven-check-style.xml or no reference for it. But looked at this solution and thought I'll give a try to see it worked " mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip"

Comment: Can fix the error in files as found in console or change the checkstyle.xml formats for each style.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas I am neither familiar with Netty nor the maven eclipse plugin, I did face an issue with the maven-checkstyle-plugin while building the [pwm](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm) project.

This was the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project pwm: Failed during checkstyle configuration ....
```

**My Solution** (which also solves many maven related errors btw):

Delete the maven's `.m2` folder, then build the project again.
On linux systems, the .m2 folder is usually in your home folder `/home/<username>/.m2`

Answer (score 2):

If you've just cloned the repository and the build failed, I believe you are using Windows and you have a problem with your Git configuration. Please set the 'core.autocrlf' option to 'true', re-clone the repository, and try again.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and I disabled checkstyle from pom, by adding the following in my pom file and it worked for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>checkstyle-validation</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is the point of having a CheckStyle plugin and disabling Validation ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just tried to execute same goal but with -X option (enabling debug level) and found what class check style plugin is complaining about. Corrected style and run maven again -> Build success.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to fix this issues by running the mvn install with -X option it will give you detail about the style issues in class. You can fix the class accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux OS I solved using **dos2unix**.

```
cd presto;
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do "mvn spotless:apply", worked for me

Comment: Yes, maven suggests to do this too sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the check-style configuration in my pom.xml and rebuilding maven. When I later re-inserted and build, it worked without error.