# How can I add a source code with markup?

Tags: java, android

Need to add it to textview, for example, standard java-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you exactly mean? You may want to change `Typeface` of `TextView` to `monospace`, this will make your TextView look similar to code block here at stackoverflow.

`This font is monospace`

Code to make it look like this:

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:text="This font is monospace" />
```

or in Java:

```
yourTextview.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Edit:

So, you need some Java code formatting library, the best would be if it returned result in HTML code, so it could be easily put into `TextView`.

I don't know if there is something like this for free, but here are few resources you may be interested in:

[How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

[Stand-alone Java code formatter/beautifier/pretty printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer)

Edit2:

You may also use one of these JavaScript libraries:

1. http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/
2. http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

along with custom `WebView` to show pretty formatted code.