# How to nicely format generated Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, import, abstract-syntax-tree, fully-qualified-naming

I am looking for a way indent the java source code automatically. I have a  tool which generates java code from other language. Now, I want to indent the generated code.
Please tell me how can I do that? in an other maner, how can i do exactely what ctl+shift+m do automatiquely?
i can not use CTRL + SHIFT + F and CTRL + SHIFT + M

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: I replaced the title question with something that actually had some relevance to the question you actually asked.  In the future, *please* make sure the title and what you ask have some relationship.

Answer (score 2):

As your tag says, you are using `Eclipse` , you can use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F` to indent the code.

Moreover as you are asking about replacing fully qualified name to import statement then no such thing exists in Eclipse as of now. ( Correct me if I am wrong ).

But you can still select the `fully qualified name` and press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `M` to import the class.

Comment: Rakesh Juyal. Thank you for your answer. But i want to have the same results that CTRL + SHIFT + F and CTRL + SHIFT + M automatically. Because the java source code generated automatically. So the source java files will be regenerated from begin in each small changes. SO it is not possible to do CTRL + SHIFT + M for all java source files generated. i want to do that automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See our [Java Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/JavaFormatter.html) for a tool that handles all dialects of Java, including version 7.

Comment: i don't search a tool, i want to create a Java classe to integrate in my plugin. Thank's

Comment: Call the tool from your plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You can select a project/folder/package in Package Explorer and format all the contents in one go using Source > Format (Ctrl+Shift+F). Or you can also configure a Clean up or a Save Action.

Comment: hte generated code change regularely. I want have an indented generated code. My technologie don't indente it so i want that this opération will be done automatiquely and in manner totaly abstract for the user. I use an AST but i don't have lot of idés. thank you very much