# Sample java code to arrange Java program according to skeleton

Tags: java, indentation

Is there any java program is available to arrange java program according to perfect indentation,syntax...? To make clear on my question (i.e) if a code snippet is like this...

**Actual Code**

```
if(true) { a=1; b=1; c=1; }
```

**Expected result**

```
if(true) {

   a=1;

   b=1:

   c=1;

}
```

Expected result can be achieved using eclipse IDE. But i want to do that using java program since am having several programs like this....

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: I doubt the you will find **simple** code to do this. Such code will need to understand Java syntax and keep some sort of AST. If you feel that the eclipse GUI doesn't provide enough functionality, you can peek at the eclipse sources.

Comment: It's not an issue of Eclipse's *functionality*, it's an issue of the OP not wanting to load up every project/file into Eclipse and run formatting.

Comment: Is there any way to use Eclipse sources to achieve the output? The way they given on the above link is not clear & clarity to me. I need more clarity/usage of that tool in command line for understandings...

Comment: Could you pls help me on this by providing such a link to use eclipse sources... like eclipse code formaters?

Comment: @Dave Newton I thought this is about lack of functionality such as scripting. The OP didn't mention multiple projects at all.

Comment: @DavidSoroko "i want to do that using java program since am having several programs like this...."

Comment: @gnubala can't help you there, you will need to google. That code will be using the Eclipse API no doubt - so you will not get a standalone code.