# Java Jalopy code formatting issue with enum

Tags: java, jalopy

I am using jalopy1.3 and when ever in a class ENUM is available on that line after applying formatting it gives below error pointer, how to fix this issue ?

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - unexpected token: Status C:\wa\Task.java:87:17: unexpected token: Status at com.triemax.cc.Q(cc.java:4500) at com.triemax.cc.A
     (cc.java:2335) at com.triemax.cc.c(cc.java:4486) at com.triemax.cc.Jb(cc.java:2833) at com.triemax.cc.e(cc.java:2458) at com.triemax.qd.a(qd.java:63) at com.triemax.vc.n(vc.java:322) at com.triemax.vc.e(vc.java:521) at com.triemax.re.b
     (re.java:26) at com.triemax.re.a(re.java:81) at com.triemax.qs.h(qs.java:59) at com.triemax.gq.a(gq.java:1) at com.triemax.ms.run(ms.java:1) at com.triemax.ps.run(ps.java:5) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    - unexpected token: CREATED C:\wa\Task.java:87:25: unexpected token: CREATED at com.triemax.cc.Db(cc.java:1344) at 
     com.triemax.cc.B(cc.java:755) at com.triemax.cc.Q(cc.java:1648) at com.triemax.cc.A(cc.java:2335) at com.triemax.cc.c(cc.java:4486) at com.triemax.cc.Jb(cc.java:2833) at com.triemax.cc.e(cc.java:2458) at com.triemax.qd.a(qd.java:63) 
     at com.triemax.vc.n(vc.java:322) at com.triemax.vc.e(vc.java:521) at com.triemax.re.b(re.java:26) at com.triemax.re.a(re.java:81) at com.triemax.qs.h(qs.java:59) at com.triemax.gq.a(gq.java:1) at com.triemax.ms.run(ms.java:1) at 
     com.triemax.ps.run(ps.java:5) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: You are using a legacy version ([jalopy 1.3](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/history-1_0.html#1_3) was released in **2004**) of a tool that haven't been much active in terms of development (the latest comercial release was in 2010). My recommendation? Switch tools! There are lot of open source alternatives as well as your IDE :).

Comment: Please provide some idea which are good one and work with same jalopy rules?

Comment: Personally? I just use IntelliJ default [code style](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-code-style.html). It works well. I have no idea about jalopy capabilities but this question may be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: About IntelliJ - Check [Java Configuration Options](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-style-java.html) to see what you can do.

Comment: so finally we are saying with jalopy 1.3 we can not support Enums :( or is there a way to achieve that for now i have this only in my company.