# How to auto-format Java code

Tags: java, git, code-formatting

**Note**: Before voting to close this question, please be aware I'm not asking any opinion about coding guidelines; I just want help automating a task.

---

I have a new colleague who likes to have exotic code guidelines like spaces everywhere:

```
obj.method( a, b );
```

or

```
@JoinColumn( name = "LANGUAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID" )
@ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = EAGER )
```

spaces.. spaces everywhere!

When you have chained code, this becomes very hard to read.

```
adapters.stream().filter( adapter -> isValidCRM( adapter.getId(), crmIds ) )
            .forEach( crmAdapter -> futures.add( CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync( () -> crmAdapter.getPerson( id ), ec ).exceptionally( throwable -> {
                        LOGGER.error( throwable.getMessage() );
                        return Response.builder().error( throwable ).build();
                    } ) ) );
```

I'm tired arguing with him and I don't want to code like that, so I did some Google searches on pre-commit git hooks and Jalopy.. but couldn't find anything useful. Jalopy seems very old (Java 1.5).

Basically, I need to auto-format code on push according to his exotic guidelines (he had configured `tt_checkstyle.xml`). On pull, I don't mind manually reformatting the code according to Java coding guidelines.

We're on Java 1.8 and I use NetBeans. We use git.

Any help (or any alternative to deal with this)? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a git hook both on server and local or set up local filters (smudge/clean)

### ***`Git hooks`***

Read the official docs for a full reference.

---

### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”, see Figure 8-2) and just before they’re staged (“clean”, see Figure 8-3).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]

Comment: great. but I need to run a command (on a hook) to indent Java according to his rules... any tool for that?

Comment: You have many tools for formatting, simply choose a good one which can be used from command line

Comment: Here is a answr with tools list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996646/stand-alone-java-code-formatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: hmm... the question is more: any tool to format according to a certain set of rules in a checkstyle.xml file? none of those seem to do it. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, i can help you with git not with Java tools. Feel free to ask any related GIT Q you might have.