# How can I make integer division in Perl OR How can I make my binary search work?

Tags: perl, int, binary-search

I'm trying to implement binary search. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;

@array = (1..100);
$number = <STDIN>;
$low = 0;
$high = $#array;

while($low < $high){
    print "Searcing $low ---- $high \n";
    $mid = $low + ($high - $low)/2;
    if($array[$mid] == $number){
        print "Found in index:" . $mid;
        last;
    }
    elsif($array[$mid] < $number){
        $low = $mid + 1;
    }
    else{
        $high = $mid - 1;
    }   
}
```

But it does not work although it is a straight forward implementation (at least it would be in Java).
It seems that I get float values when dividing and can not search. If I provide as input `5` I get garbage:

```
5  
Searcing 0 ---- 99  
Searcing 0 ---- 48.5  
Searcing 0 ---- 23.25  
Searcing 0 ---- 10.625  
Searcing 0 ---- 4.3125  
Searcing 3.15625 ---- 4.3125
```

How can I make it use integer numbers so I can index the array?
Also if I uncomment `use strict` I get the following errors. What do they mean?

```
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at D:\Development\Perl\chapter3\binarySearch.pl line 6.  
Global symbol "$number" requires explicit package name at D:\Development\Perl\chapter3\binarySearch.pl line 9.  
Global symbol "$low" requires explicit package name at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the function [int](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html).

Aside from that, you need to `use strict;` and use `my` to scope your variables.  This will catch errors that you might miss.  Just declare them like this:

```
my @array = (1..100);
chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);
my $low = 0;
my $high = $#array;

my $mid = int ($low + ($high - $low)/2);
```

You might consider using [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) too, to remove newlines from your input.

Comment: So `my` missing is the reason this does not run on `strict` right?

Comment: @Cratylus Yes, this is why it complains about it requiring an explicit package name.  Learn to love it though, as `strict` really catches errors that you might overlook.

Comment: Actually int is not a casting operator, it is a function. As in perl there is no strict types of a variable, there is no need for a cast operator.

Answer (score 6):

```
my $int = int 5 / 2;
print $int;
```

Prints 2.

Comment: Is that a cast to integer?

Comment: Also what is `my`?Do I need it? Is this the reason for the errors on using `strict`?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html Basically, it's good practice to use strict and properly localize variables with my. Do you need it? No. Should you use it, yes.

Comment: @Cratylus - you've already been told what `my` is today in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933254/how-do-you-reference-a-list-in-perl)

Comment: @chrsblck:I been reading about `Perl` for the last couple of days.I don't get most of it yet, so I ask again to get it

Comment: @Cratylus - read what you're linked to then. No need to ask the same question over and over.

Answer (score 3):

Use the good old `>> 1` instead of `/2`.

Example:

```
perl -e 'BEGIN { print 5/2, " : ", 5>>1}'
```

Output:

```
2.5 : 2
```

And use (spare an substraction):

```
my $mid = ($low + $high) >> 1;
```

Comment: Is this a signed division? Is there a symbol for unsigned division? (like `>>>` in `Java` )

Comment: @Cratylus: Nope. You can use the `int -5/2` version.

Answer (score 3):

Two esoteric solutions. Don't actually use these unless you are really bored or something.

1. `use integer` -- a pragma that forces Perl to treat all your numerical values as integers. It can be locally scoped so it won't ruin all the data in your program

   ```
   while($low < $high){
       print "Searcing $low ---- $high \n";
       {
           use integer;
           $mid = $low + ($high - $low)/2;
       }
       if($array[$mid] == $number){
           print "Found in index:" . $mid;
           last;
       }
       elsif($array[$mid] < $number){
           $low = $mid + 1;
       }
       else{
           $high = $mid - 1;
       }   
   }
   ```
2. Perl has some special variables [`$=`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#FORMAT_LINES_PER_PAGE), [`$-`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#FORMAT_LINES_LEFT), and [`$%`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#FORMAT_PAGE_NUMBER) that will only hold integer values, no matter what you assign to them. Use them directly

   ```
   $- = $low + ($high - $low) / 2;
   if ($array[$-] == $number) { ...
   ```

   or as intermediates

   ```
   my $mid = $- = $low + ($high - $low) / 2;
   if ($array[$mid] == $number) { ...
   ```

   Using the magic variables like this is handy for [code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977483/168657) and irritating your co-workers, but not much else.

Comment: Why doesn't `Perl` treat a numerical value as an integer when used as an array index?I mean in my OP I assume that the `48.5` printed is not used as `48` to index the array and that is the reason the binary search does not work

Comment: It does. `$array[48.5]` will return the same value as `$array[48]`.

Comment: So why does the code works only if I use `int()` for the `mid`?

Comment: Because otherwise `$high` and `$low` might contain floating point values, and your stopping condition `$high >= $low` will never be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with your code.

- You disabled [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

  Presumably because of the next problem.
- You didn't declare any of your variables, with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) or [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) or even [`use vars`](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html).

  ```
  our @array = 1..100;
  use vars qw'$mid $low $high';
  my $number = <STDIN>
  ```
- You worry too much about overflows. This isn't C.

  If your number would overflow an integer, it just becomes a float.

  ```
  my $mid = $low + ($high - $low)/2;
  ```

  Should probably just be:

  ```
  my $mid = ($high + $low)/2;
  ```
- You expected an integer out of a division.

  ```
  my $mid = ($high + $low)/2;
  ```

  If you really want an integer just use [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html).

  ```
  my $mid = int( ($high + $low)/2 );
  ```
- You didn't remove the newline from the end of `$number`

  ```
  chomp($number);
  ```
- You have an off by one error.

  ```
  while($low < $high){
  ```

  Should really be

  ```
  while($low <= $high){
  ```

  This is really your main problem.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = 1..100;
my $number = <STDIN>;
chomp $number;
my $low = 0;
my $high = $#array;

while($low <= $high){
    my $mid = int( ($high + $low)/2 );
    printf "Searching %2d .. (%2d) .. %2d\n", $low, $mid, $high;
    if($array[$mid] == $number){
        print "Found $number at index mid $mid\n";
        last;
    }elsif($array[$mid] < $number){
        $low = $mid + 1;
    }else{
        $high = $mid - 1;
    }
}
```

That's not really Perlish though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw'first_index';

my @array = 1..100;
my $number = <STDIN>;
chomp $number;

my $index = first_index { $_ == $number } @array;
print "Found $number at index ", $index if $index != -1;
```

Or more bizarrely

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = 1..100;
my $number = <STDIN>;
chomp $number;

my $char = join '', map chr, @array;

my $index = index $char, chr $number;
print "Found $number at index $index\n" if $index != -1;
```

This works with numbers up-to the lesser of `UV` max or `(2 ** 72) - 1`.
That is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 on 64-bit builds, and 4,294,967,295 on 32-bit builds.

Comment: +1.I didn't get this `If your number would overflow an integer, it just becomes a float.` and the perlish examples are completely incomprehensible to me (a Perl newbie)

Comment: @Cratylus The first Perlish example just iterates over the list returning the index where it becomes true. The second bizarre Perl example takes advantage of the UTF8-style string handling capabilities of Perl. ( It's not actually very Perlish )

Comment: I could/should have written [`my $char = join '', map chr, @array;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html "perldoc -f chr") as [`my $char = pack 'U*', @array;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html "perldoc -f pack").

Comment: `first_index { $_ == $number }` is this an inline function?

Comment: @Cratylus [`first_index`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#first_index-BLOCK-LIST "perldoc List::MoreUtils") is written to be used similar to [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html "perldoc -f grep").

Comment: You mean that `first_index` is another existing method?

Comment: @Cratylus [`first_index`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#first_index-BLOCK-LIST "perldoc List::MoreUtils") is a subroutine that someone wrote, it is **not** part of Perl. (follow the link)

Comment: Oh sorry.Did not realize there was a link! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
my $mid = $low + ($high - $low)/2
```

can be simplified to

```
my $mid = ($high + $low)/2;
```

You can get the integral part using [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html)

```
my $mid = int( ($high + $low)/2 );
```

Or you could take advantage of the fact that a bit shift is an integer division by 2.

```
my $mid = ($high + $low) >> 1;
```

See also: [Flexible Binary Search Function](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=383504#binsearch)

Comment: `$low+($high-$low)/2` is an idiom from C that handles the case where the result of `$low+$high` is larger than the largest int value. It's probably less useful in Perl.

Comment: @mob, Yeah, it's only a problem if you can have an array whose number of elements is more half of the addressable space. That's not going to happen in Perl since at each element requires at least sizeof(void*) bytes. Even if you ignore that, you'd never have a problem with a 32-bit Perl build since 2**53 or 2**64 (number range) is far more than 2**33 (2 * index range). You could possibly have a problem in 64-bit builds if you have an array with ~10,000,000,000,000,000,000 elements or more (which, like I said, can't happen in Perl).

Comment: @ikegami:I think this answer and your comment is incorrect.I used the `low + (high - low)/2` to avoid overflow.I believe this should be possible to happen in `Perl` as we can index an array via `int` indexes only which are signed and have `2^32 - 1` addressable elements. So I am not sure what you mean about `number of elements is more half of the addressable space etc` in your comment

Comment: @ikegami:Also concerning `($high + $low) >> 1;` is this signed or unsigned division?

Comment: @Cratylus, Currently, unsigned.