# Tried converting bash script to perl, no avail

Tags: perl, bash

I tried converting this function.

```
R1=`cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/rx_bytes`
T1=`cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/tx_bytes`
sleep $INTERVAL
R2=`cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/rx_bytes`
T2=`cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/tx_bytes`
TBPS=`expr $T2 - $T1`
RBPS=`expr $R2 - $R1`
TKBPS=`expr $TBPS / 1024`
RKBPS=`expr $RBPS / 1024`
echo "TX $1: $TKBPS kb/s RX $1: $RKBPS kb/s"
```

To this in perl:

```
my $rx = `cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/rx_bytes`;
my $tx = `cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/tx_bytes`;

my $rx1 = `cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/rx_bytes`;
my $tx1 = `cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/tx_bytes`;

my $tb = $tx1 - $tx;
my $rb = $rx1 - $rx;

my $kbs = $tb / 1024;
my $rbs = $rb / 1024;
sleep 1;
print "$kbs $rbs\n";
```

Bash script output:

```
TX eth1: 10 kB/s RX eth1: 16 kB/s
TX eth1: 10 kB/s RX eth1: 15 kB/s
TX eth1: 10 kB/s RX eth1: 16 kB/s
TX eth1: 9 kB/s RX eth1: 14 kB/s
```

Perl script output:

```
0.158203125 0.212890625
0.22265625 0.14453125
0.052734375 0.072265625
0 0.072265625
0 0.140625
```

As you can see its not outputting what I think it should be, any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Your bash script output does not match the `echo` statement in the bash script code you give. There is a difference between bits and bytes, so you either have a typo in your output, or you are missing code from your function.

In any case, `expr` will return an integer if you divide two integers, while Perl will return a floating-point number if you divide two integers.

If you need an integer result from the Perl script, look into explicitly casting your number arguments with the `int` keyword. For an example, see: [How can I make integer division in Perl OR How can I make my binary search work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935870/how-can-i-make-integer-division-in-perl-or-how-can-i-make-my-binary-search-work)

Comment: Thank you i fixed the code perfectly, using printf, and forgot to put the sleep between where it gets the data.